# sending array to $_POST by checkbox

Tags: php, post, global-variables

i have a problem on my friends server when testing my php code on it.(it works fine in my local server).

there is a form that contain `checkbox` inputs like

when submitting the form:

1. In my server : print_r($_POST) prints:
   `Array ( [names] => Array ( [0] => john [1] => sam ) )`
2. In his server : print_r($_POST) prints:
   `Array ( [names] => Array )`

and `Array` is a string not an array !

his php version is `5.2.17`

```
<form method="post">
john <input type="checkbox" name="names[]" value="john"/>
sam <input type="checkbox" name="names[]" value="sam"/>
moh <input type="checkbox" name="names[]" value="moh"/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
<?php 
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Comment: What do you get if you do `print_r($_REQUEST)`?

Comment: @Night2 so What do you think the problem is ?

Comment: So you are absolutely having some code that is touching the $_POST before you print_r it, that code may have different results in different php versions or settings ...

Comment: yes there is a code touches $_POST but it is : $_POST   = array_map('stripslashes',$_POST);(to stop magic_qoutes)

Comment: aha ... i get it stripslashes($_POST['names']).. and it is not string it's array .... thanks man :)

Comment: I posted the final answer with a function for you to use ...

Comment: just a note: you mentioned PHP v 5.2 -- please note that support for v5.2 was discontinued nearly two years ago. It is time to upgrade. Current version is v5.4, and I hear good progress is being made on v5.5. Don't let yourself get too far behind.

Comment: thanks for advice :).. it is my friend's old bad server !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From comments of first post here is the answer:

You are doing this which is wrong: `$_POST = array_map('stripslashes',$_POST);`

That's exactly the cause of this problem, using `stripslashes` on every element of `$_POST` is worng, `stripslashes` works on strings and an array in string is equal to "Array" so that function is doing the convert of your array to `"Array"`, you should write a custom function and check if the element is not an array use stripslashes or if it is use the array_map again, like this:

```
<?php

function stripslashes_custom($value){
    if(is_array($value)){
        return array_map('stripslashes_custom', $value);
    }else{
        return stripslashes($value);
    }
}

$_POST = array_map('stripslashes_custom', $_POST);

?>
```

The reason of different results on array input for stripslashes function is probably due the different php versions ...

Comment: It is better if magic quotes are on, to give an error message and tell the admin that this needs to be changed. It is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

As you know, you can't change `magic_quotes_gpc` with `ini_set()`. If `magic_quotes_gpc` in php.ini is `Off` this code below will be skipped as stripslashing isn't needed. Otherwise for `magic_quotes_gpc = On`, this function will be executed recursively to stripslash all strings in arrays instead of using `array_map()`.

I've tested it with PHP 5.2.17 (mode `On`) and with 5.3.10 (mode `Off`).

So here we go with that easy code:

```
<?php

function stripslashesIterator($POST){
    if ($POST){
        if (is_array($POST)){
            foreach($POST as $key=>$value){
                $POST[$key]=stripslashesIterator($POST[$key]);
            }
        }else{
            return stripslashes($POST);
        }
        return $POST;
    }
}

//Init $_POST, $_GET or $_COOKIE
if (function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc') && get_magic_quotes_gpc() === 1){
    $_POST=stripslashesIterator($_POST);
}

?>
```

Comment: Useless answer, this is pretty much the same like the existing variant. If magic quotes are on, give error message and tell the admin that this needs to be changed. It is deprecated.